# Teamsisu/contao-greyify doesn't work in contao

Tags: contao

I have download Teamsisu/contao-greyify and upload in vendor/ teamsisu folder.
Then give the inserttag

```
{{greyify::assets/images/9/Vicus-wint-iCMG-Enterprise-IT-Architecture-Excellence-Award-2016_banner-a428ab58.png/UUID?width=x&height=x&mode=x}}
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use paths from the `assets/images` directory, since that is just the image cache. You need to reference the source image instead. You probably misinterpreted the [README](https://github.com/Teamsisu/contao-greyify/blob/master/README.md) of the extension. You either use the path to the source image - *or* you provide the UUID of the file.

#### Example with image path

```
{{greyify::files/public/banner.png?width=200&height=100&mode=crop}}
```

#### Example with image UUID

```
{{greyify::c42739fa-39b8-11e9-b257-8c1645f08cc5?width=200}}
```

Comment: I have no public folder Is it correct                  {{greyify::files/vicus/volleybal_vicus_foto.jpg?width=200&height=100&mode=crop}}

Comment: how to find UUID of the image

Comment: The folder does not need to be called `public` it just needs to _be_ public. i.e. you have to set it to _Public_ in the file manager of the Contao back end.

Comment: You can find the UUID of an image by clicking the info symbol (i) of the file in the file manager of the Contao back end. Using the UUID is preferable.

Comment: {{greyify::32ee7d9c-69c7-11e7-abbc-2e3e7a222c66?width=200}}     give like this but didn't work